# Referencing multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How do I reference multiple tables for one table ?

In the assignment, I have to create 5 tables with each table having `INT id:
Owners, homes, home_owners, installation, house_type`.
Owners can have multiple homes and homes can have multiple owners.
Home needs to have installations and house_type(both need to be `VARCHAR` type).

I wrote this to sql but it returns an

> error: errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

```
CREATE TABLE owners (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
created DATETIME,
modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE homes (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
created DATETIME,
modified DATETIME,
home_types_group VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE home_owners (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
created DATETIME,
modified DATETIME,
owners_num INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY owners_num_key (owners_num) REFERENCES owners(id)
);

CREATE TABLE installation (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
brands VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
created DATETIME,
modified DATETIME,
FOREIGN KEY brands_key (brands)  REFERENCES homes(home_types_group)
);

CREATE TABLE types (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
types VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
created DATETIME,
modified DATETIME,
FOREIGN KEY brands_key (types)  REFERENCES homes(home_types_group)
);
```

Comment: you have to add index on varchar fields before add a constraint

Comment: can you explain in code pls

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
CREATE TABLE installation ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, brands VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created DATETIME, modified DATETIME, FOREIGN KEY brands_key (brands)  REFERENCES homes(home_types_group) )
```

**REFERENCES homes(home_types_group)** : this is wrong, you can only reference a primary or unique column of some table for making foreign key. But **home_types_group** column is neither primary nor unique. Change it to **id** clumn of homes table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> CREATE TABLE installation ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, brands
>   int, created DATETIME, modified DATETIME, FOREIGN KEY fk_id(brands) 
>   REFERENCES homes(id) );
>
> CREATE TABLE types ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, types int,
>   created DATETIME, modified DATETIME, FOREIGN KEY brands_key (types) 
>   REFERENCES homes(id) );

You can create a foreign key by defining a FOREIGN KEY constraint when you create or modify a table. In a foreign key reference, a link is created between two tables when the column or columns that hold the primary key value for one table are referenced by the column or columns in another table

Here REFERENCES homes(home_types_group)  is wrong so you should change it to homes(id), you can only reference a primary or unique column of some table for making foreign key.and both keys data type should be same that is

> brands VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
>   types VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

are wrong it should be int

Comment: brands should be characters not integers

Comment: You should change last two queries